# Monitoring Rsync Progress

Tags: python, progress, rsync

I'm trying to write a Python script which will monitor an rsync transfer, and provide a (rough) estimate of percentage progress. For my first attempt, I looked at an `rsync --progress` command and saw that it prints messages such as:

```
1614 100%    1.54MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#5, to-check=4/10)
```

I wrote a parser for such messages, and used the to-check part to produce a percentage progress, here, this would be 60% complete.

However, there are two flaws in this:

- In large transfers, the "numerator" of the to-check fraction doesn't seem to monotonically decrease, so the percentage completeness can jump backwards.
- Such a message is not printed for all files, meaning that the progress can jump forwards.

I've had a look at other alternatives of messages to use, but haven't managed to find anything. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The values jump because rsync starts transferring data while it's still evaluating the work it has to do. It's as good a measure as any you will get.

Comment: Is there no way to make it pre-evaluate the work it needs to do? --dry-run --stats seems to be the kind of thing to do this, unfortunately the values it produces for data to be transferred are not correct.

Comment: why would you slow it down, just to make it show useless information?

Comment: Well, it's not useless information... I'm transferring gigabytes at a time, and it's important to give the user a useful idea of progress, without printing messages left, right and centre? An extra minute or so on a transfer that will take half an hour, to show the user roughly how long it's going to take, seems like a reasonable trade-off to me.

Comment: there is no "printing messages left, right and centre," it simply updates the progress information as it learns more.

Answer (score 30):

The current version of rsync (at the time of editing 3.1.2) has an option `--info=progress2` which will show you progress of the entire transfer instead of individual files.

From [the man page](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html):

> There is also a --info=progress2 option that outputs statistics based on the whole transfer, rather than individual files. Use this flag without outputting a filename (e.g. avoid -v or specify --info=name0 if you want to see how the transfer is doing without scrolling the screen with a lot of names. (You don't need to specify the --progress option in order to use --info=progress2.)

So, if possible on your system you could upgrade rsync to a current version which contains that option.

Comment: If I could only compile rsync on MinGW :/

Comment: "Beginning with [rsync 3.0.0](https://man.archlinux.org/man/extra/rsync/rsync.1.en), the recursive algorithm used is now an incremental scan that uses much less memory than before and begins the transfer after the scanning of the first few directories have been completed." My understanding is that "the whole transfer" they refer to there is the part it learned about so far. As it learns more, the percentage jumps backwards. `--no-inc-recursive` will make it precompile the whole list of files to be transferred. Which will make it report the correct percentage from the beginning.

Comment: ...But that will need more memory. More on the output [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261139/29867).

Answer (score 9):

You can disable the incremental recursion with the argument `--no-inc-recursive`.  rsync will do a pre-scan of the entire directory structure, so it knows the total number of files it has to check.

This is actually the old way it recursed.  Incremental recursion, the current default, was added for speed.

Answer (score 7):

Note the caveat here that even `--info=progress2` is **not** entirely reliable since this is percentage based on the number of files rsync *knows* about at the time when the progress is being displayed. This is not necessarily the total number of files that needed to be sync'd (for instance, if it discovers a large number of large files in a deeply nested directory).

One way to ensure that `--info=progress2` doesn't *jump back* in the progress indication would be to force rsync to scan all the directories recursively before starting the sync (instead of its default behavior of doing an incrementally recursive scan), by also providing the `--no-inc-recursive` option. Note however that this option will also increase rsync memory usage and run-time.

Comment: this works great for me, thanks for explanation of option

Answer (score 0):

For full control over the transfer you should use a more low-level diff tool and manage directory listing and data transfer yourself.

Based on librsync there is either the command line [rdiff](http://librsync.sourcefrog.net/doc/rdiff.html) or the python module [pysync](http://freshmeat.net/projects/pysync/)